# How to mantain values if submit fails PHP

Tags: php

I have a form that is being validated using PHP server side scripting. The form's action is also to itself. To show multiple errors, I store it in an array and used foreach to loop through the values and echo it for dislay. I thought i'm finished using PHP validation but I noticed that everytime I submit the form, even though it still contains some errors, all of the values that were inputted resets. Why? When I used javascript, the values remains so whats with PHP?

This is how I set my errors and insert data to db.

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
$lname = $_POST["lname"];

$errors = array();

if(strlen($lname) == 0)
{
$errors[] = "Last name is required";
}

if (!empty(errors))
{
//display errors using foreach loop
}
else
{
//connect and insert data to mysql db
}

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

in your form's input element code use it like this

```
<input type="text" name="username" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['username']) echo $_POST['username'];?>">
```

using isset to check if value exist or not and than echoing it

Comment: You forgot passing value through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: yeah thats upto developer its a filter and a good practice to pass the value through this filter before eachoing

Answer (score 1):

You perhaps write your HTML form without setting up default values.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" />
```

In the case of an error you should set up a default value. Here an example. Do not forget to sanitize your POST vars before outputting.

```
<input type="text" name="firstname" value="<?php echo $_POST['firstname']; ?>" />
```

Comment: You forgot passing value through `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: There can be multiple filters that apply to the output. But thanks, I have added a notice that the OP should not directly spill the form values into HTML. But I am sure, Mei knows what she does!

Comment: Someone told me that sending the data to itself is not appropriate because of the fact that it will send the data again if it's refresh. The right way is to send the data to a data handler(another page), then use sessions. That was someones answer to my question.

This was the code he recommends.

    <?php
    unset($_SESSION['last_data']);
    unset($_SESSION['errors']);
    if(errors)
    {
    //set error session here
    $_SESSION['last_data']=$_POST;
    }
    else
    {
    //update/insert database
    }

Comment: @Mei, in simple words, if there are errors in posted data, it's safe to resend them on page refresh, as it will just generate another error (it is safe, isn't it?). Resending data is a problem in case of success, as that would generate another successful POST and possibly add 2 identical rows in DB (e.g., create two comments instead of only one, or making two purchase orders instead of only one). You should read about [PRG design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) for more info.

Comment: @Mei, as for sending data to the data handler - it may be the same page (URI) as long as it can separate data editing requests from data retrieval requests and act accordingly.

Comment: So what's the preferred way? Doing this with session or without session?

Comment: Mei, you did ask why your form is empty. We told you to setup default values to your form elements. If you want to ask something about SESSION, please open another question here on StackOverflow. And don't forget to mark our answers here accepted and helpful (vote or click grey checkbox).

Comment: Oh. I understand. Thanks for the all the answer. It really helps when you know that there are a variety of options available.

Comment: You are welcome. These comment section is only for very short comments and not meant to be a discussion forum :-)